# heroku run rake task to download files

Tags: heroku, download, rake

I know that Heroku does not have a persistent filesystem, and I know that if I want to create files on Heroku, I can put them in /tmp ... And they will of course be temporary.

Can I create a rake task that will generate files on Heroku (we can assume it's files that just write 'hello world' and are called 'world1.txt' and so on) and download them to my local machine?

I imagine the steps would be something like:

1. get data
2. write files in /tmp
3. ?
4. profit

So I imagine something like this:

```
$ heroku run rake gimme
Downloading your files, O my lord and master...
You have your files, O my lord and master.
$ ls
[ My files ! ]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

No. I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: Well, I daresay, why not? what gets in the way of that? And who can I talk to, in order to make this possible?

Comment: AFAIK you are not supposed to write files to /tmp either.  Your app is meant to be completely file-less in that regard. Why not write the file content to a db and download via a REST api or something?

Comment: Because that would mean adding security to make sure only the people who should access this information can access the information. I was hoping for something less .. heavy-handed. But maybe it's my sysadmin tendencies coming back out.